# Storybook - how to remove "Setup controls >" link from Controls

Tags: reactjs, storybook

When using storybook (with react, to be exact), when I disable controls for a specific arg by setting `{ control: false }` in `argTypes` (or if I don't specify a particular argument in `argTypes`,

and then run the project, in my browser, that property has `-` in `control` column (in `Controls` tab), but when I hover it, a link `Setup controls >` appears...

Is there any way to remove it?

To be clear - I want the property to be listed in Controls, but I don't want to provide any action for it - just description.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the control type to `{}` it will remove the link and just have a "-"

e.g.

```
argTypes: {
    Color: { control: { type: {} } },
  },
```

Comment: While this may work now, it may not in the future.